# MySQL DATEDIFF and TO_DAYS returning very large and incorrect values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to calculate the number of days between the current date and a date in a table.  The date is at most a few months in the past or future. However, when trying to calculate this delta with either datediff or to_days we are sometimes seeing wildly incorrect values, even after verifying the dates in the table are within 90 days of the current date.

Consider the following snippet, where s.enroll_begin is a DATE field

```
SELECT 
... /*35 other columns */
to_days(curdate()) as todayToDays,
s.enroll_begin as fieldAsDate,
to_days(s.enroll_begin) as fieldAsToDays,
DATEDIFF(s.enroll_begin,curdate()) as dateDelta
```

This is throwing an exception (e.g. '21474836484' in column '39' is outside valid range for the datatype INTEGER) in our DAO when attempting to put dateDelta into an int field.  when debugging, we are seeing values like these for the above columns:

```
todayToDays:737546
fieldAsDate:3/1/19 12:00 AM 
fieldAsToDays:**-2.66287234868E11**
dateDelta:**4294967478**
```

The last two fields are clearly wrong.  What is especially odd is that error does not happen on every query.   A kludge would be to create as java date object using the fieldAsDate value and do the math in java.  but this should be doable directly within the SQL

Environment:
MySQL 5.7.25 (Ubuntu 16.04)
Tomcat 8.5.33
Java 1.8.0_181
JDBC Pool Library:  HikariCP 3.3.1

Comment: Which is the type of `enroll_begin` ?

Comment: What is the difference between `s.enroll_begin` and `s.enroll_start`?

Comment: enroll_begin is type DATE

Comment: Add also the type of `s.enroll_start`

Comment: apologies - that is a typo.   There is just one date column:

Comment: This is the SQL:

SELECT 
to_days(curdate()) as todayToDays,
s.enroll_begin as fieldAsDate,
to_days(s.enroll_begin) as fieldAsToDays,
DATEDIFF(s.enroll_begin,curdate()) as dateDelta

Comment: `DATE`s have a limited range between 1000-01-01 and 9999-12-31.  This cannot produce an arithmetic overflow via `datediff()` on the current date.  Something strange is going on -- I would guess it involves the types going back to java.

Comment: some additional info... I tried re-arranging the order of the columns in the SQL and oddly this changed some of the behaviour.  For example, trying to do a rs.getString("asStringColumn") would sometimes throw an out of bounds exception.  (yet the length of the actual data was not even 90 characters).

it all seems to suggest a bug in JDBC, HikariCP or MySQL but I want to rule out a bug in my sql

Comment: p.s.  using mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.  I tried switching to the v8.0 connector but got same problem